# AzureAD and OpenIdConnect session expiration in ASP.net WebForms

Tags: asp.net, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, adal

I have an ASP.net WebForms application, which I have configured to work with Azure Active Directory and OpenIDConnect based on this article:
http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/07/24/protecting-an-asp-net-webforms-app-with-openid-connect-and-azure-ad/

Generally speaking, it works fine. But sometimes, after a longer period of inactivity (e.g. filling out a big form), the user is redirected to the main page of the app and his data from the form is lost. This is of course very confusing.

It seems that at some point the session (token?) expires and it needs to re-authenticate. I was able to track a HTTP 302 to https://login.windows.net/... at the point of the redirect. So it would confirm my assumption about re-authentication via AAD.

I cannot exactly tell how often this happens - for me it does not seem to be in regular intervals. I was trying to reproduce the behavior by deleting the cookies `AspNet.Cookies` and `ASP.NET_SessionId` but it did not cause the redirect. Interacting with the application just recreated those cookies automatically.

My questions are:

1. Is there some other location (local storage?) where the information about the login is saved?
2. How can I (silently, in the background) make sure that the session/token is valid?

Answer (score 1):

In your initialisation code, assuming you've followed the instructions in the article you've linked, there's a line like so,

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
```

When delegating authentication to an Identity Provider, your application still drops some cookies based on the authentication result that control lifetimes. You can tweak these settings to your requirements....e.g.

```
appBuilder.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType ="Cookies",
    ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60), // Expire after an hour
    SlidingExpiration = true // use sliding expiration..
});
```

Have a look at the docs for the things you can configure - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dn385599(v%3Dvs.113)

Also, an event will be raised whenever it thinks it needs to interact with the Identity Provider, handler optoions available under the Notifications object on OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions. One you might be interested in is **RedirectToIdentityProvider**

```
private void ConfigureOpenIdConnect()
{
    var openIdConnectAuthenticationOptions = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        // the rest of your settings....then
        Notifications =
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
              RedirectToIdentityProvider =
                    async context => await RedirectToIdentityProviderHandler(context)
            },
            UseTokenLifetime = false
    };
}            

private static Task RedirectToIdentityProviderHandler(
    RedirectToIdentityProviderNotification<OpenIdConnectMessage, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions> notification)
{
    // do some logging whenever you app is redirecting to the IDP
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

UseTokenLifetime is interesting here, as your identity token has an expiration time and by default the cookie lifetime in the application is the life of the token. If you want to control the cookie lifetime yourself (as per the first code snippet), set this to false here and explicitly control this yourself.

You could use a combination of overriding the identity token lifetime, a longer cookie lifetime, setting sliding expiration to true + some logging on whenever Redirects happen to the Identity Provider.

Obviously though, tweaking settings too much increases attack vector, so consider your security requirements carefully.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, you will get ID token after login successfully via AAD. ID token is Jwt format with an expiration time. You can change the ID token's lifetime with powershell. Please refer to this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-configurable-token-lifetimes#access-token-lifetime.